# South African Slang "Nu"

Tags: slang, nicknames, south-african-english

Any idea what Nu means when someone uses it as a nickname for someone else in South Africa?

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to upset OP, but [oxforddictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nunu) has...

> **nunu** also **noonoo** Pronunciation: /ˈnuːnuː/
>   South African INFORMAL
>    An insect, spider, worm, or similar small creature:
>    *the box gives protection against worms and other nunus*
>
> from Zulu **inunu** 'horrible object or animal'

And [here's someone who knows that](http://www.iol.co.za/news/south-africa/hau-my-china-it-s-bakgat-1.94509?ot=inmsa.ArticlePrintPageLayout.ot), commenting on the usage as an informal/affectionate term...

> *So, girls, if your boyfriend uses **nunu** in its lighter meaning, as a term of endearment and affection, think again - his motives might be sinister!*

---

I can't think of an equivalent English term offhand, but French [*mon petit chou*](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080918143143AAXmkfK) *(my little cabbage)* comes to mind.

Comment: I asked around and looked up nunu as a nickname and it seems to be a term of endearment.  Something people call their grandkids. Thanks. Nunu has info on it but a search for Nu just came up with a definition of now.

Comment: My mother's favorite term of endearment is *bogárkám* = "my little insect".

Comment: "Bug" is a slightly dated (southern?) American term for the same thing.

Comment: @Preston: I did think about mentioning ***bug***, but my impression is it's like ***shrimp*** - usually used of *younger siblings*, rather than romantic partners.

Answer (score 1):

In South Africa, anything cute is referred to as "nunus".  Nunu is a term of endearment (what my husband calls me).  And if my cat does something precious - we say she is being nunus.  It's a very loosely used and adaptable noun and adverb.